Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be added to a Sequential model
I encountered an error related to Sequential while working with TensorFlow Hub. Can anyone help me with this?"
enter image description here
"ValueError: Only instances of keras.Layer can be added to a Sequential model. Received: <tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x78b89f3d15d0> (of type <class 'tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer'>)"
I've reviewed some research and found that version issues were mentioned, but I believe my problem isn't related to that. When I change keras version to '2.17.0' I recieved this error ->
enter image description here

The problem was solved and it was caused by the version. When using TensorFlow version 2.15.0, the tensorflow_hub.KerasLayer function was accepted, and the code block worked well.

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

The issue is due to version incompatibility. You can resolve this by downgrading TensorFlow, TensorFlow Hub, and Keras to compatible versions. Try running the following commands to install the versions that are known to work together:
pip install tensorflow==2.15.0 tensorflow-hub keras==2.15.0
Once you've installed the correct versions, your code should work without the ValueError: Only instances of keras.Layer can be added to a Sequential model error.

This worked for me!

I used the great recommendation given by @adam-de-nyangos (I apologize as I don't know how to link to him)
Look in this post :
error : Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be added to a Sequential model
These are the things I did:
Added or modified this instruccions:
!pip install tf_keras -q  # notice -q for quiet installation (maybe it is not needed as it could be installed properly)

import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tf_keras

In my case I was following a Udemy training for NLP so I wanted a encoder+decoder layers:
sentence_encoder_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4",
                                        input_shape=[],
                                        dtype=tf.string,
                                        trainable=False,
                                        name="USE")



model_6 = tf_keras.Sequential([  
  sentence_encoder_layer,   # THIS LINE WAS MY PAINTFUL CODE with the mentioned error...
  tf_keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"), # Use tf_keras.layers.Dense
  tf_keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="output_layer") # Use tf_keras.layers.Dense
], name="model_6_USE")

and finally rest of code worked. Notice I also needed to change Adam optimizer to tf_keras.optimizer.Adam() as no mix of tf_keras and keras could be produce.
I am not an expert and probably others could explain better than me but I assume keras version in colab is different from tf_keras. (model.summary seems the old keras 2 version)....
Hope this helps you too :)
[![Picture where you can see the code]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/rzmLrfkZ.png
